# Secure Repositories by User in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have followed the many helpful ideas presented in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818571/how-to-setup-mercurial-and-hgwebdir-on-iis).  Now the last thing I'm wrestling with is how to allow certain people to access and view the contents of certain repositories.  I want to have a central Repos folder on my machine, where all Hg Repos will live, but I would like to say that Person X can see Repos A, B and C while Person Y can only see A & C.  I have not been able to find the answer to this question and I hoped that someone on SO could assist me.  I can control the push/pull, but I haven't seen a way to actually prevent repos from being visible in the hgwebdir CGI application.

Comment: What OS/webserver are you using? You could perhaps use the webserver's auth to limit access to certain repos.

Comment: Windows/IIS7 But my understanding is that access to the collections is done via the AppPool user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ACL Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AclExtension) (distributed with Mercurial).

Comment: Have you used this extension in a Windows/IIS deployment of mercurial?

Comment: God no, one would be crazy to use IIS for anything. :)  But it should work just fine.  It's all in python land and you can get the username into the system via environment variable.

Comment: What web server have you used the ACL Extension in? (I appologize for the inqusition).  Were you able to secure repos so that people could read, read/write, or not even view them within the hgwebdir?

Comment: I don't use it, but plenty of folks do.

You can do read-only vs. read-write with it.  Hiding you'll want to use your HTTP server for.