# Mercurial 1.6 Web Interface on Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis, mercurial, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to get the Mercurial web interface running on my Windows Server through IIS.  All the tutorials online are out of date and I've tried to stumble through them, but things are just too different between the Python, Mercurial, and IIS versions.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck with a Windows server.  Has anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup Mercurial and hgwebdir on IIS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818571/how-to-setup-mercurial-and-hgwebdir-on-iis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to setup Mercurial and hgwebdir on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818571/how-to-setup-mercurial-and-hgwebdir-on-iis/2766947#2766947)

Check here if you've come across this question.  Not sure why google didn't work for this but looks like I found an answer!